# how to use copyto api in phonegap

Tags: database, cordova, file-copying

i want to copy a sqlite db to the database folder but dont know how to use copyto api:

```
function win(entry) {
console.log("New Path: " + entry.fullPath);
}

function fail(error) {
 alert(error.code);
}

function copyFile(entry) {
 var parent = document.getElementById('parent').value,
    parentEntry = new DirectoryEntry({fullPath: parent});

 // copy the file to a new directory and rename it
 entry.copyTo(parentEntry, "file.copy", success, fail);
}
```

what is entry? where to i have to write my db path form assets folder? is it mistyping that in the last line it said success but didn't define it? do i have to write win instead?

Answer (score 1):

The File API can't access files inside the asset directory. You'll need to write a plugin.

Comment: thank you Simon
i wanted to create a sqlite db and copy it to the database forlder in the first run. so as i see the only way is to import a xml or other kind of db(like lawnchair) into sqlite in the first run of app. am i right?

Comment: is there any way to use a pre-stored db in phonegap?

Answer (score 1):

I did it by adding some code to my main activity(java code):

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

     import android.app.Activity;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.widget.EditText;

    public class main extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        String pName = this.getClass().getPackage().getName();
        try
        {
        this.copy("Databases.db","/data/data/"+pName+"/app_database/");
        }

        catch (IOException e)


    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    }

    void copy(String file, String folder) throws IOException 
    {

        File CheckDirectory;
        CheckDirectory = new File(folder);
        if (!CheckDirectory.exists())
        { 
            CheckDirectory.mkdir();
        }

        InputStream in = getApplicationContext().getAssets().open(file);
        OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(folder+file);

        // Transfer bytes from in to out
        byte[] buf = new byte[1024];
        int len; while ((len = in.read(buf)) > 0) out.write(buf, 0, len);
        in.close(); out.close();

    }
    }
```

source:
    http://gauravstomar.blogspot.com/2011/08/prepopulate-sqlite-in-phonegap.html

Comment: Thanks for answering this. I'm going to be pasting your blog post into a lot of answers on the google group.